# Passing a macro argument to an if == test in jinja?

Tags: macros, jinja2

I'm using Tarbell to publish a formatted version of an inventory spreadsheet. Every row has a category, so I can do something like this:

```
<h2>Power Tools</h2>
{% for row in inventory %}
  {% if row.Category == "powertools" %}
    <b>{{ row.Display_Name|e }}</b> <br />
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<h2>A/V Gear</h2>
{% for row in inventory %}
  {% if row.Category == "av" %}
    <b>{{ row.Display_Name|e }}</b><br />
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

To get a list of all the power tools followed by a list of A/V gear. I'd like to move that into a macro that I can call with a couple of arguments. I've got this:

```
  {% macro list(cat, title='') -%}
      <p>Category: {{ cat }}; Header: {{ title }}</p>
      {% for row in inventory %}
        {% if row.Category == "{{ cat }}" %}
          <b>{{ row.Display_Name|e }}</b><br />
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
  {%- endmacro %}
```

When I call it with:

```
  {{ list('av', title='Cameras and Audio Recorders')}}
  {{ list('powertools', title='Power Tools')}}
```

I see "Category: powertools; Header: Power Tools" and "Category: av; Header: Cameras and Audio Recorders" as expected, so I know the macro can hear me, but the list itself doesn't show up. Can I use a macro argument in a comparison test? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for variable interpolation syntax inside of a block - you can just refer to the variable by name as you would in Python:

```
{# Do this #}
{% if row.Category == cat %}

{# Instead of this #}
{% if row.Category == "{{ cat }}" %}
```